# ionic2: can't navigate to another page from popover

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I'm using Ionic2, I want to open another page when user choose a page to open from popover, this the code from the first page:

```
popvarSpecialsArr = ['Home','My Account','Cart','Wishlist','My Orders'];
presentPopoverSpecial(myEvent) {
let popover = this.popoverCtrl.create(MorePopverPage, {popvarArr: this.popvarSpecialsArr});
console.log('my event', myEvent);
popover.present({
  ev: myEvent
});

}
```

this the code from popover page:

```
popvarArr;

constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
NavParams,public viewCtrl: ViewController) {
this.popvarArr = this.navParams.get('popvarArr');
console.log(this.navParams.get('popvarArr'));
}

openPage(page) {
console.log(page);
if(page == 'Home') {
  console.log('inside home');
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
} else if(page == 'My Account') {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyAccountPage);
} else if(page == 'Cart') {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(CartPage);
} else if(page == 'Wishlist') {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(WishlistPage);
} else if(page == 'My Orders') {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(MyOrdersPage);
} else if(page == 'Specials') {
  this.navCtrl.setRoot(SpecialsPage);
}
}
```

and this is the popover Html code

```
<ion-content no-padding no-margin>
<ion-list no-lines no-padding no-margin>
    <button ion-item *ngFor="let popvar of popvarArr" (click)="openPage(popvar)">{{popvar}}</button>
    <!-- <button ion-item (click)="close()">Home</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">My Account</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Cart</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">Wishlist</button>
    <button ion-item (click)="close()">My Orders</button> -->
</ion-list>
```

but when I choose a page from the popover it doesn't display the page that I want and still in the same page, what should I do to display other pages from the popover

Comment: Are you calling function openPage(page) from MorePopverPage ?

Comment: @RafałGołubowicz yes i edited the post and enter the html code

Comment: @RafałGołubowicz yes i edited the post and enter the html code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like you can see in **[the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#navigating-from-an-overlay-component)**:

> What if you wanted to navigate from an overlay component (popover,
>   modal, alert, etc)? In this example, we've displayed a popover in our
>   app. From the popover, we'll get a reference of the root
>   `NavController` in our app, using the `getRootNav()` method.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
    template: `
    <ion-content>
      <h1>My PopoverPage</h1>
      <button ion-button (click)="pushPage()">Call pushPage</button>
     </ion-content>
    `
  })
  class PopoverPage {
    constructor(
      public viewCtrl: ViewController
      public appCtrl: App
    ) {}

    pushPage() {
      this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
      this.appCtrl.getRootNav().push(SecondPage);
    }
  }
```

So in your case, it'd look like this:

```
import { App, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

// ...

 constructor(public viewCtrl: ViewController, public appCtrl: App) {}

// ...

openPage(page) {
    console.log(page);

    // Close the popover
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();

    if(page == 'Home') {
        console.log('inside home');
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(HomePage);
    } else if(page == 'My Account') {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(MyAccountPage);
    } else if(page == 'Cart') {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(CartPage);
    } else if(page == 'Wishlist') {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(WishlistPage);
    } else if(page == 'My Orders') {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(MyOrdersPage);
    } else if(page == 'Specials') {
        this.appCtrl.getRootNav().setRoot(SpecialsPage);
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 1):

> (getRootNav) is deprecated and will be removed in the next major
>   release. Use getRootNavById instead.

You should use:

```
 this.appCtrl.getRootNavs()[0].setRoot('LoginPage');
```

which is instead of `getRootNavById()` method.